# CONCAT year and month from date and add custom day

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, concatenation

I am trying to concat the year and month of a date and add a custom day in Google bigQuery. Is that possible?

My QUery

```
SELECT  
CONCAT(((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM reportdt)), '-', (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdt)), '01')
) AS 
yo,
brandnm,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM reportdt) as the_year,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdt) as the_month 
FROM  table
WHERE reportdt BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-11-30'
```

My error:

```
"No matching signature for function CONCAT for argument types: STRUCT<INT64, STRING, INT64>. Supported signatures: CONCAT(STRING, [STRING, ...]); CONCAT(BYTES, [BYTES, ...]) at [2:1]"
```

Expected result for

`SELECT

    CONCAT(((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM reportdt)), '-', (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdt)), '01') AS yo`

```
2018-05-01
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DATE_TRUNC(reportdt, MONTH)` instead

So your query will look as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT  
  DATE_TRUNC(reportdt, MONTH) AS yo,
  brandnm,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM reportdt) AS the_year,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdt) AS the_month 
FROM  `project.dataset.table`
WHERE reportdt BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-11-30'
```

If for some reason you are bound to use of CONCAT here - see below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT  
  CONCAT(CAST((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM reportdt)) AS STRING), '-', CAST((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdt)) AS STRING), '-01') AS yo,
  brandnm,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM reportdt) AS the_year,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdt) AS the_month 
FROM  `project.dataset.table`
WHERE reportdt BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-11-30'
```

Comment: Awesome! short, neat and perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using `CAST()`

```
SELECT  
CONCAT((CAST((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM reportdt)) as STRING), '-', CAST((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdt)) as STRING), '01')
) AS 
yo,
brandnm,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM reportdt) as the_year,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdt) as the_month 
FROM  table
WHERE reportdt BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-11-30'
```